# ngx-youtube-player angular component with div toggle play pause

Tags: angular, youtube, components, toggle, video-player

What I am trying to do with ngx-youtube-player is to make div transparent on top of it which on click toggles play and pause video. Why i am doing this because my Angular project has many components and one way to navigate through is using keyboard (arrow up and down). 
With Youtube player of any kind, those controls are blocked.

How to achieve this?

In video.component.html

```
<div class="content" (click)="playVideo()"></div>
  <div class="video">
    <youtube-player [videoId]="id" (ready)="savePlayer($event)"(change)="onStateChange($event)">
    </youtube-player>
  </div>
```

video.component.ts

```
id = 'btfgGf2wDgI';
 private player;
 private ytEvent;

playVideo() {
    this.player.playVideo();
  }

pauseVideo() {
    this.player.pauseVideo();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using the new Angular 9 component 'youtube-player' it is easy!

```
npm install @angular/youtube-player
```

app.module:

```
imports: [    YouTubePlayerModule ]
```

html:

```
<youtube-player videoId={{videoId}} [width]=300 [height]=150 
            [startSeconds]=9
            (apiChange)="OnApiChange($event)"
            (stateChange)="videoStateChange($event)"
            (ready)="videoReady($event)"></youtube-player>
```

Then in typescript:

```
videoStateChange( e ) {
       console.log( "videoStateChange: ", e
    if( e.data == 5 ) {
      console.log( "VIDEO STATE == 5")
        e.target.playVideo();
    }
}
```

Check the console.log to see all other available functions like pauseVideo etc.